# How do I take user input from a text field, then change their input into an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm working on making a basic grade calculator app that asks the user to enter their grades like this ( 66, 77, 88, etc). When they press the calculate button, it is going to take their input and change it into an array. How do I do that, though? I've looked around on here, apple's website, and treehouse, so I'll appreciate any help that will guide me in the right way. I do not want an exact answer, just some guidance to find the right answer.

Comment: Is it gonna be a single textField ? you can use componentsSeparatedByString(",")

Comment: iTunes University has lectures from Stanford; one series by Paul Hegarty actually handles this exact concept and builds a stack-calculator as you referred to. It might be beneficial for you to review, very helpful overall.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByString`.

**Example**:

```
let input = "66, 77, 88"
// Remove any whitespace to avoid user error
let gradesString = input.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
let myStrings = gradesString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

// Convert array of [String] to [Double]
var myGrades = [Double]()
for string in myStrings {
    myGrades.append(Double(string))
}

// Use myGrades
```

Comment: much easier to use ", " instead of ","

Comment: @LeoDabus Not necessarily. What if the user did not enter a space after each comma? It is best to assume that the user is stupid or that they will make mistakes. Trimming whitespaces and using "," will avoid this user error.